# Prove that $u(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}c(w)e^{-iwx}e^{-kw^2t}dw\rightarrow 0$ if $x\rightarrow \infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have the following problem:

Be the equation:

$$u(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}c(w)e^{-iwx}e^{-kw^2t}dw$$

Show that $u\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$, even when $e^{-iwx}$ does not falter if $x\rightarrow \infty$.

The problem gives the hint to use integration by parts. I was hoping you explain this problem or help me solve it, for your attention and any help: thank you very much.

Comment: After completing squares you get
$$e^{-\frac{x^2}{4kt}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty c(w)e^{-kt \left(w +  \frac{ix}{4 (kt)^2}\right )^2}dw $$
the inner thing looks like Gaussian distribution of some function.

Comment: Crossposted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112271/2451